# C# Consolse Apps Got error The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden using WebClient also HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, download, console-application, webclient

i'm new in this programming world. So i got a task to download zip file from url via C# Console Application, i've tried many things but still got same error. I've already add some Headers in my code also based on Fiddler Result.

This is my code:

```
WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
            webclient.Headers.Add("sec-ch-ua-mobile", "?0");
            webclient.Headers.Add("sec-ch-ua-platform", "windows");
            webclient.Headers.Add("upgrade-insecure-requests", "1");
            webclient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "mozilla/5.0 (windows nt 10.0; win64; x64) applewebkit/537.36 (khtml, like gecko) chrome/98.0.4758.102 safari/537.36");
            webclient.Headers.Add("accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,/;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9");
            webclient.Headers.Add("sec-fetch-site", "cross-site");
            webclient.Headers.Add("sec-fetch-mode", "navigate");
            webclient.Headers.Add("sec-fetch-user", "?1");
            webclient.Headers.Add("sec-fetch-dest", "document");
            webclient.Headers.Add("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
            webclient.Headers.Add("accept-language", "id-id,id;q=0.9,en-us;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,ms;q=0.6,th;q=0.5");
            webclient.DownloadFile(url, @"d:\data.zip");
```

Is there any missed? or should i take other way?

Thanks
Regards,
Alvin

Comment: "i've tried many things but still got same error", can please share the error you are getting, that might help to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

403 is mean HTTP forbidden. It's usually using authentication like an API_KEY or any authentication but refused or fail.

Make sure your API_KEY is right.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403

Comment: the url is a public url. and any user can download the data. If this the case, i think no need to use any API Key or specific authentication right? Is there any relation between i run from console application?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add the URL from where you want to download that zip?

Comment: This one is the link: https://www.idx.co.id/Portals/0/StaticData/ListedCompanies/Corporate_Actions/New_Info_JSX/Jenis_Informasi/01_Laporan_Keuangan/02_Soft_Copy_Laporan_Keuangan//Laporan%20Keuangan%20Tahun%202021/Audit/AALI/instance.zip